# Get first word after slash in a URL in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Trying to create a column which only returns the first word after slash in urls. So for example, for

```
https://stacoverflow.com/questions/ask 
https://qwerty.com/search/go
```

return only **questions** for first example
return only **search** for second example

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's linking to a bogus site.

Comment: The site was just an example

Comment: I've edited to prevent people from clicking on it.

Comment: based on your sample url, what is your desired result?

Comment: Based on the sample url, I only want questions to be returned. SInce it's the first word after the first slash

Comment: Can you please share the code your wrote that didn't return the desired output?

Comment: I am not sure how to approach this problem, that's why posting it, wondering if anyone has any thoughts?

Comment: The [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) might be helpful here.

Comment: One approach: start by removing the leading https://, then find the first and second /, get the characters between these 2 positions

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at the [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) function in Redshift

```sql
select SPLIT_PART('https://stacoverflow.com/questions/ask', '/', 4)
select SPLIT_PART('https://qwerty.com/search/go', '/', 4)
```

Splits a string on the specified delimiter and returns the part at the specified position.